# Mongo Map Reduce with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce

I am new to mongo, I am trying to count the number of entries for a list of "codes"

eg.

the data in a field called "CODE"

```
asd
fgh
jkl
asd
```

the idea I am trying to work out is how to do the equivalent of MySQL:

```
select count(id) from table where (CODE='asd' or CODE='fgh') group by CODE
```

so that it returns:

```
asd 2
fgh 1
```

and ignores jkl stats

given the following starting point:

```
$db = $connection->$database;
$collection = $db->$table;
```

how would I go about this, I have read up on map/reduce in mongo, but at the moment it isn't making a lot of sense to me.

Some guidance in getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Map Reduce or you could use the aggregation framework which may make more sense here for a SQL person:

```
$collection->aggregate(array(
    array('$match' => array('CODE' => array('$in' => array('asd','fgh')))),
    array('$group' => array('_id' => '$CODE', 'count' => array('$sum' => 1)))
));
```

Which is analogous to:

```
select count(id) from table where (CODE='asd' or CODE='fgh') group by CODE
```

And will return:

```
{
    {_id: asd, count: 2},
    //next document
}
```

As reference you can read through the documentation and look at the examples here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/

Comment: Thank you for your help, got it working! 

Only thing I needed to change was to change:

    array('$group' => array('_id' => 'CODE', 'count' => array('$sum' => 1)))


to

    array('$group' => array('_id' => '$CODE', 'count' => array('$sum' => 1)))

Comment: @CharlieSmith Ops yeah made a mistake there :)

Comment: @Sammaye why don't you fix the mistake in the answer then?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Cos the OP already found out how to fix it, but ok I'll edit